# MSTest not being executed when run by Cruisecontrol schedule

Tags: msbuild, mstest, cruisecontrol

Some background:  Im trying to implement the integration of Cruisecontrol (2.8.4), MSBuild and MSTest on my current project (.Net 4.0 and VS 2010).  I'm using MSBuild to build my solution and added a MSTest as AfterBuild Target into my .csproj files to run my unit tests:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild" DependsOnTargets="GetTestAssemblies" >
<Message Text="Normal Test" />
<Exec Command="del $(MSTestResultsFile)" ContinueOnError="true" />
<Exec WorkingDirectory="$(WorkingDir)" Command="MsTest @(TestAssemblies->'%(TestContainerPrefix)%(FullPath)',' ') /noisolation /resultsfile:$(MSTestResultsFile)" />
<Message Text="Normal Test Done" />
```

I've configured cruisecontrol.config to use MSBuild, ie:

```
<schedule interval="300">
    <exec command="cmd.exe"
            workingdir="C:\CruiseControl\projects\Framework"
            args="msbuild Solution.sln" />
</schedule>
```

When I run the build from the command prompt ie: cmd.exe:

```
msbuild <projectname>.sln
```

, the solution and projects builds correctly, the unit tests runs and outputs the results to the `/resultsfile:$(MSTestResultsFile)` specified.

My problem is when the  command in the cruisecontrol schedule is executed, the build (MSBuild) actually succeededs but my MSTest: `/resultsfile:$(MSTestResultsFile)` is empty.  It seems that the unit tests wasn't run at all.

I have no clue why this is happening?
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By change the cruisecontrol schedule config to use the msbuild.exe in stead of cmd.exe resulted in the unit tests being executed

```
<schedule interval="300">
    <exec command="msbuild.exe"
                    workingdir="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319"
                    args="C:\CruiseControl\projects\DTSFramework\DTS.Solution.sln" />
</schedule>
```